# Error importing python library gedit external tools

Tags: python, bioinformatics, gedit

I am trying to create a shortcut that execute on the selection this simple python code.
It just run a function from the library Biopython.

```
#!/Users/USERNAME/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python

from Bio.Seq import reverse_complement
import sys

print reverse_complement(sys.stdin.read().rstrip())
```

But I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named Bio.Seq
```

It does not make sense to me since if I run from the terminal

```
$ /Users/USERNAME/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
>>> from Bio.Seq import reverse_complement
```

The library is imported without any problem.
What do I do wrong? How do I tell gedit where to look for the library?

Comment: If you put `print sys.executable` before the last line, what do you get?  (both *run in terminal*, *run not in terminal*)

Comment: gedit:
`/Users/gioelelamanno/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

Terminal:
`/Users/gioelelamanno/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with your path.
This should work:

```
#!/Users/USERNAME/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python

import sys
sys.path.append('*yourpath of Bio module*')
from Bio.Seq import reverse_complement


print reverse_complement(sys.stdin.read().rstrip())
```

Comment: Any clue why gedit is using:
`/Users/gioelelamanno/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/C‌​ontents/MacOS/Python`
instead of what I tell him to use?

Comment: And how to avoid that what is after my selection is sent to a new line?

Comment: I am not familiar with gedit, your shebang (first line) look fine for me.

Comment: I don't get the second question, can you be more specific?

Comment: for example I want to produce the reverse_complement() of:
AAAAAAA seqN1
And I want to get:
TTTTTTT seqN1
But when I select AAAAAA what happens is that I get:
TTTTTTT <<newline>>
seqN1

Comment: why don't yu pass it via sys.argv[1:]. 
or you could try 
print reverse_complement(sys.stdin.read().rstrip().replace("\r","").replace("\n","")) ...

Comment: This happen for any code. it is gedit that after printing adds a "\n"

Comment: why gedit? your are running it with python, gedit is just the source code editor...